# How to change text back into button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a simple game using HTML, JS, and CSS that uses buttons that can reveal different answers depending on what question you pick. However, once you click on a button, the answer just stays there and there is no way to turn it back into a button aside from refreshing the page, which clears the Scoreboard. Is there a way to make a "Reset" button that will turn the answers back into buttons?

So far, I've tried turning them back using CSS. Here is what I have right now:

```
.button {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

However, being relatively new to HTML, JS, and CSS, I'm not quite sure what to do now. Does anyone have a solution?

BTW the buttons were made using HTML and the code to reveal answers was done using JS.

Answer (score -1):

Does the answer replace the button on click, or is it a toggle button that you are looking for that controls the display of the answer.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you click on the button, an answer is revealed. From then on, the answer just sits there.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class                  Have a look at this.. what you need to do is add a class on click of the button to whatever element has your answer. The class your adding has to have a display property other than "none". Before adding a class to it, make sure the element has display: none

Comment: So what should I do then if the button is inside a table?

Comment: Would this work?

Code for the button:
```
            <tr>
              <td id="ans2"><div><input type="button" value="2" style="height:30px;width:350px;" onclick="giveAnswer(2)"></div></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Ask for clarification in comments, not answers.

Comment: Could you provide the css and js function definition as well